# get big query table schema from select statements

Tags: google-bigquery

I realize there's a million ways to get a schema from a dataset.table in google big query....

is there a way to get schema data via a select statement? such like querying sql servers INFORMATION_SCHEMA table?

Thanks.

Comment: sometimes looking into the problem from another angle helps - so what is your use case? why you think you need getting schema via select statement?

Comment: I need to perform data profiling, and the only tool I have is the QUERY function on the webui.  I want to create a query that counts nulls, non-nulls, string lengths, and such per column.

Comment: Hi arcee, remember to add a @MikhailBerlyant in your comments so he gets notified by SO about your messages ;)

Comment: Also, for me it's been hard to understand why you need the schema for that. You don't know a priori about the tables schema? Do you have maybe an example of what you want to accomplish?

Comment: @Willian Fuks so I can do something like this: http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/Data+Profiling/96398/

Comment: sorry for joke - but it's like you want to fly to moon but the only what you have is car! you might reconsider tools you want to use to achieve this! just having QUERY in UI in your disposal is not going to fly for what you referenced! you most likely should consider calling api and building some simple client-side web app

Comment: yeah, no access to that.  it's a client thing....so I thought I woudl try this.

Comment: in this case  - yo should consider downsizing your plan down to something more realistic but still close to what you initially wanted. consider giving up on something and/or splitting that big "something" to smaller pieces

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> I need to perform data profiling, and the only tool I have is the QUERY function on the webui. I want to create a query that counts nulls, non-nulls, string lengths, and such per column

Below is to give you potential direction/idea to explore and enhance up to your needs
It works relatively good for for simple schemas - looks like needs to be tuned for  schemas with records and repeated
Also, note it skips columns which are NULLs in all rows of the table - so such columns are not visible for below approach

So, with `fh-bigquery.reddit.subreddits` as a simple test table  :

```sql
#standardSQL
WITH `table` AS (
  SELECT * FROM `fh-bigquery.reddit.subreddits`
),
table_as_json AS (
  SELECT  REGEXP_REPLACE(TO_JSON_STRING(t), r'^{|}$', '') AS row
  FROM `table` AS t
),
pairs AS (
  SELECT 
    REPLACE(column_name, '"', '') AS column_name, 
    IF(SAFE_CAST(column_value AS STRING)='null',NULL,column_value) AS column_value
  FROM table_as_json, UNNEST(SPLIT(row, ',"')) AS z, 
  UNNEST([SPLIT(z, ':')[SAFE_OFFSET(0)]]) AS column_name,
  UNNEST([SPLIT(z, ':')[SAFE_OFFSET(1)]]) AS column_value
)
SELECT 
  column_name,
  COUNT(DISTINCT column_value) AS _distinct_values,
  COUNTIF(column_value IS NULL) AS _nulls,
  COUNTIF(column_value IS NOT NULL) AS _non_nulls,
  MIN(LENGTH(SAFE_CAST(column_value AS STRING))) AS _min_length,
  MAX(LENGTH(SAFE_CAST(column_value AS STRING))) AS _max_length,
  ROUND(AVG(LENGTH(SAFE_CAST(column_value AS STRING)))) AS _avr_length
FROM pairs 
WHERE column_name <> ''
GROUP BY column_name
ORDER BY column_name
```

Result is

```sql
column_name   _nulls    _non_nulls  _min_length _max_length _avr_length  
-----------   ------  ----------  ----------- ----------- -----------
c_posts       0       2499          1            4             4.0   
created_utc   0       2499         14           14            14.0   
downs         0       2499          1            8             5.0   
num_comments  0       2499          1            7             5.0   
score         0       2499          1            7             5.0   
subr          0       2499          4           23            12.0   
ups           0       2499          1            8             5.0
```

I think it is very close to what is called profiling (and within the scope of what is available for you)
You can easily add any column metrics, etc.

I really think - this can be good starting point for you

Comment: I appreciate it...but this gives me record data....I'm looking for schema information.  The other solutions suggest using api's and command lines.  I do not have access to that.  so I need to use a select statement to run this.

Comment: understood - just gave as an option. but from what i know there is no real way to get table schema with select statement. bq or api - easily. select - not sure

Comment: this is the second time you saved my bacon.....you sir should write a book.  let me know when you do.  I'll buy it.

Comment: is there any chance you could add count of distinct values?

Comment: On the road now. Will add when back to comp. but you can try by yourself - hint - count(distinct ...)

Comment: added _distinct_values

Comment: The key seems to be `TO_JSON_STRING(t)` but I don't see TABLE as a valid type to pass in at https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/json_functions#to_json_string What does the JSON look like when I pass in a table? Answer: it's converting each row in the table to JSON. It doesn't return any extra metadata about the schema.

Comment: @TimSwast - please clarify - is this a question or you just commenting. not sure. if this is a question  - i will answer

Comment: It was a question, but then I answered it myself. I hoped the query would get the metadata from the table somehow, but it actually gets the rows.

Answer (score 1):

Mikhail's answer is still relevant if the goal is to compute information like the number of null values and non-null values per column. To answer the original question, though, BigQuery provides support for [INFORMATION_SCHEMA views](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/information-schema-intro), which are in beta at the time of this writing. If you want to get the schema of a table, you can query the [`COLUMNS` view](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/information-schema-tables#columns_view), e.g.:

```
SELECT column_name, data_type
FROM `fh-bigquery`.reddit.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
WHERE table_name = 'subreddits'
ORDER BY ordinal_position
```

This returns:

```
Row column_name     data_type   
1   subr            STRING
2   created_utc     TIMESTAMP
3   score           INT64
4   num_comments    INT64
5   c_posts         INT64
6   ups             INT64
7   downs           INT64
```