# Listing All Tables and Fields Google BigQuery

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

Is there a SQL query I can use in the Web UI in Google BigQuery that would return a list of all of the tables and fields/schema within a database? So far I've only been able to find a "**TABLES_SUMMARY**" command but that does not give me any info on the fields/schema. I do not want to have to click on each individual table to see what's in it.

Comment: Alas, no.  Google doesn't (yet) provide the INFORMATION.SCHEMA tables/views.

Comment: ...but please follow [the relevant feature request](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/35906063) for updates (you can click the "star" to express interest).

Answer (score 4):

BigQuery provides support for [INFORMATION_SCHEMA views](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/information-schema-intro), which are in beta at the time of this writing. If you want to get the schema of multiple tables, you can query the [`COLUMNS` view](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/information-schema-tables#columns_view), e.g.:

```
SELECT table_name, column_name, data_type
FROM `bigquery-public-data`.stackoverflow.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
ORDER BY table_name, ordinal_position
```

This returns:

```
Row table_name  column_name         data_type   
1   badges      id                  INT64
2   badges      name                STRING
3   badges      date                TIMESTAMP
4   badges      user_id             INT64
5   badges      class               INT64
6   badges      tag_based           BOOL
7   comments    id                  INT64
8   comments    text                STRING
9   comments    creation_date       TIMESTAMP
10  comments    post_id             INT64
11  comments    user_id             INT64
12  comments    user_display_name   STRING
13  comments    score               INT64
...
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try below query

SELECT * 
FROM [DB Name].INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
ORDER BY TABLE_NAME

Answer (score 0):

someone posted a workaround [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45337079/get-big-query-table-schema-from-select-statements/45337150#45337150).

Depending on how many columns you have, you can do something similar without much hassle